# Storing HTML to mysql in Python

Tags: python, html, mysql

I need to store crawled HTML pages which were first stored locally. I am opening the file successfully using

```
myHTML = open(file_location,'r').read()
```

output is available from here:http://shrib.com/jqR5uf0C

I also successfully create the SQL query:

```
query_insert = ("insert into job_html (processid, myURL, myhtml) VALUES (%d, %s, %s)", processid, my_url, str(myHTML))
```

but for some reason the HTML isn't escaped properly as I cannot insert this via Python or manually.

I am also getting the following Python Error:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Any help is appreciated from a Python novice ;-)

Code:

def extractText(file_location,processid,my_url):

```
import mysql.connector

iwr_db = mysql.connector.connect(user='iwr', password='iwr',
                          host='127.0.0.1',
                          database='iwr_1')

myHTML = open(file_location,'r').read()
query_insert = ("insert into job_html (processid, myURL, myhtml) VALUES (%d, %s, %s)", processid, my_url, str(myHTML))
print query_insert

cursor_insert = iwr_db.cursor(buffered=True)
cursor_insert.execute(query_insert)
iwr_db.commit()
```

Comment: Where is a) the actual MySQLdb execute call and b) the full traceback?

Comment: in the same function. It works as when I replace the HTML with a simple string it is imported correctly. When I print the SQL query and try to manually insert it to mysql then it fails also. Not sure what you mean by 'traceback'

Comment: Sigh. When I say "where is it" I mean "please can you post it".

Comment: Thanks Daniel - see amended post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that for some reason you are defining your query as a tuple and then trying to pass that directly to the `execute` command.

I think that you are confused about the difference between this:

```
query = ('foo', bar, baz)
execute(query)
```

and this:

```
execute('foo', bar, baz)
```

In the first, you define a tuple, which is then passed to `execute` as a *single* parameter - hence the error message about tuples. In the second, of course, you are passing three separate parameters to `execute`.

You *could* fix this by using what's called "tuple unpacking" when you call execute:

```
execute(*query)
```

but in your case it would simply by easier to define the query string as one variable, and pass the rest to execute directly:

```
query_insert = "insert into job_html (processid, myURL, myhtml) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
cursor.execute(query_insert, processid, my_url, str(myHTML))
```

(Also note that *all* parameters to a MySQLdb query string must use `%s`, even if they are integers.)

Comment: That worked perfectly Daniel!!! Only had to add brackets around the set of arguments: cursor.execute(query_insert, (processid, my_url, str(myHTML)))